# Update method of serializer only creates and doesn't update (Django rest framework)

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm having a hard time with nested serializers, especially updating them. So far I can update the lesson description and all the main fields before the nested serializer (like course description, title etc). Ideally I'd like to search using `lesson_id,` and not `lesson.title` like it is now, and update description and title at the same time. Is there a workaround for that?

My **models.py**

```
class Course (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField (max_length=150)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="No Description")
    student = models.ManyToManyField(Student, related_name='courses', blank=True)
    teacher = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher, related_name='teacher', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Lesson (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(default="No Description")
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lessons')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Serializers.py** where the problem is

```
class CourseSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):

    lessons = LessonSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    #teacher = TeacherSerializer(many=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'lessons')  #to separate serializer with students for teachers later

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        lessons = validated_data.pop('lessons', [])
        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
        for lesson in lessons:
            lesson, updated = Lesson.objects.update_or_create( defaults={'description': lesson["description"]},  title= lesson["title"]) 
            #pk = instance.lessons_id doesn't work, I cannot get this id
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

**Views**

```
class CourseDetailDeleteView (generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUserOrAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourseSerializer

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = CourseSerializer(instance=self.get_object(), data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is that `validated_data["lessons"][0]["id"]` doesn't exists:

By default the `id` field of a `ModelSerializer` is read_only, so `id` is not included in `validated_data` in `.create() or .update()`. Thus you'll have to override that:

```
class LessonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    ....

    ## Optional: in case you don't want `id` getting explicitly set
    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data.pop("id", None)
        return super().create(self, validated_data)

    ## Optional: in case you don't want `id` of the instance getting updated
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        validated_data.pop("id", None)
        return super().update(self, instance, validated_data)
```

---

Another note:
There's no way to know if `serializer.save()` is even called in `CourseDetailDeleteView.update`. I would suggest to set `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` instead so it can return error messages and show you why it didn't save.

Comment: Wow! I didn't find the info that `id` field is read-only in `ModelSerializer`, since it is included in my `fields`, I was expecting it to be there. Thanks, Kyell, there is no way I could have figured it out without your help here!